# USB 3G Mobile connection available in Debian (Virtualbox)

Tags: usb, debian, virtualbox, 3g

is there anyway to enable network connection(Internet) from Win 7 over VirtualBox to Debian 64. Whan am at work I use WiFi and I can make FTP/SSH connection from my Win7 to Debian, but at home I have USB 3G mobile connection (Huawei E173) and I cant connect to Debian... And in Debian I have only terminal with no GUI.

When am at home, in Win, ipconfig shows this:

Windows IP Configuration

**PPP adapter T-Mobile HR:**
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.210.245.66
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0

**Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 9:**
Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

**Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 6:**
Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

**Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 8:**
Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

**Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 3:**
Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

**Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:**
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::7c30:94ad:b516:b67f%52
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.137.1
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

**Tunnel adapter isatap.....**

Any ideao how to configure network so I can have isntant connection in Debian over NAT or bridger connection or w/e.

Thanks!

Comment: Come on, please any1, how can I get ip? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

WiFi and cellular modems are tricky beasts with virtualization products - I am guessing you have tried using the guest networking configured as a bridge?

I would suggest using two virtual network adapters for your Debian guest:

- Adapter 1 - Configured as NAT
- Adapter 2 - Configured as Host-Only

The idea here is that the NAT adapter will act as the primary gateway to allow your guest access to the same networks your host can see - e.g. your LAN at work and the internet over your 3G modem. The second Host-Only adapter is to provide a stable interface that you can use to reliably connect to your Debian host regardless of other network states.

Reference: Chapter 6: Virtual Networking 
http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html